# how to do if statement with dataframes in this code?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I fix the following code? It gives the error:Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

```
 import pandas as pd    
    bank = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\OĞUZ\Downloads\halkbank.csv')
    bank=bank.set_index('Tarih')
    bank=bank.iloc[0:15,0:4]
    bank = bank.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '.'))
    bank = bank.astype('float64')
    pctchange=(bank['Yüksek']-bank['Düşük'])/bank['Düşük']
    def risk(bank):
        if pctchange>0.30:
            val='High Risk'
        elif pctchange>0.20:
            val='Middle Risk'
        else:
            val='Low Risk'
        return val
    bank.apply(risk,axis=1)
    print(bank)
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or a snippet of `halkbank.csv` file?

Comment: I think you wanted to use different parameter in `risk` function: `risk(pctchange)`, not `risk(bank)`.

Comment: Mustafa hocam teşekkürler. Peki ben neden "bank = bank.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '.'))
    bank = bank.astype('float64')" bu kodu kullanmak zorundayım anlayamadım

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
... 
bank = bank.astype('float64')

# Set filters like this
mask1 = (bank['Yüksek']-bank['Düşük'])-bank['Düşük'] > 0.2
mask2 = (bank['Yüksek']-bank['Düşük'])-bank['Düşük'] > 0.3

# Creat new column 'Risk'
bank.loc[:, 'Risk'] = 'Low Risk'  # By default
bank.loc[mask1, 'Risk'] = 'Middle Risk'
bank.loc[mask2, 'Risk'] = 'High Risk'

print(bank)
```